# Warning: move_uploaded_file(): it is moved but the Filesize stays at zero

Tags: php, file-upload, chown

I have been using an upload script on my server, like below

```
$newname = time() . '_' . $_FILES[$file]["name"];
if (strtolower(end(explode('.', $_FILES[$file]["name"]))) != 'pdf' AND $file != "damage_attachment_damageform_1" AND $file != "damage_attachment_damageform_2" AND $file != "damage_attachment_damageform_3" AND $file != "damage_attachment_damageform_4") {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"], $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/components/com_fleet/uploads/docs/' . $newname)) {
        $images[] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/components/com_fleet/uploads/docs/' . $newname;
        $docs[] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/components/com_fleet/uploads/docs/' . $newname;
    } else {
        die();
    }
}
```

It uploads an image fine, but since a few days a get a `Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move`  error. Ive seen these a dozen of times while learning to program, so I did all the usual stuff, check paths, the $_FILES[$file]["error"] and check all the right CHMODs. All is fine, path is spot-on, chmod is too, no errors etc...

1 extra weird thing I noticed the file does get written to the right /docs map but its Filesize is empty, and `move_upload_file` still sends `false`...

What am I forgetting? CHOWN maybe? And how can I solve that, I dont have SSH access or something.

Comment: File without size means, it is getting copied, but the source seems not valid. did u print_r "$_FILES[$file]["tmp_name"]" ?

Comment: yes I did, I printed everything and all was fine. It as valid just being blocked by the servers disk quota. Thanks tho

Comment: Never wld've guessed it ;D

Comment: Do you check that file has successfully uploaded with is_uploaded_file ?

Comment: @sk8terboi87 haha me neither, really got me crazy, and it was so simple... I feel ashamed :D

Answer (score 2):

Graa after an hour I now found out what was wrong, server Disk Quota was exceeded. Maybe people can still benefit from my problems...

Comment: If it eases your pain you've probably just saved me an extra few hours of confused searching.

Comment: Haha, glad to be of service. It's so obvious you can't think of it :)